# internationalizing combo boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, combobox

We have a WinForms application that is currently being internationalized. While some controls are straightforward to be i18n'ed, combo boxes with drop down items are giving us a hard time. Take a combo box with the following drop down items:

```
year
month
day
```

Currently these items are provided in the designer and the text values are persisted in the application database. I know it was not too bright idea to begin with but this where we are now.

I suspect I will need to go for a key/value type list and assign that as the data source to the combo box. The question is what would be the best practice to accomplish this task?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use combo box, we have two properties, one is "Text" and "Value". You have to set the text value from the localized resource file and Value field always from your code.

```
cbxJobTile.Item.Text  ="Localized string from resource file";
cbxJobTile.Item.Value = "SoftwareEngineer";
```